# Change colour of buttons when one is selected; Android development

Tags: android, xml, button, android-xml, android-drawable

So I am making an app with 3 buttons. Currently I have the following .xml file that makes them have rounded off edges and be the colour red. Now I want to to make them so if one is selected then that button turns green while the other two remain, or turn back to red. How could I go about doing this? Do I have to make another .xml file? 
Here is my drawable .xml file for the buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <!--red colour.-->
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/> 
    <corners
         android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#000000"/>
 </shape>
```

Comment: Yes you need to write different drawables with diffrent solid and stroke color.

Comment: I'd use a RadioGrop with 3 RadioButtons, instead - to **maintain the pressed state** (Button states are momentary). You can remove the button graphics and use a custom selector with the red/green states as the background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `selector` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- green state -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected" 
        android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <!-- green state -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" 
        android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <!-- red state -->
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled"></item>

</selector>
```

Then, you should call this selector like:

```
<Button
     ...
     android:background="@drawable/my_selector" />
```

And create each `drawable.xml` (as your example for the red button) for every state: **button_selected**, **button_pressed** and **button_disabled**.

You can also remain the state by using `onTouchListener` like:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // change the color
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // intitial color
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});
```

However, it's better to use a `Selector` and a `background`, this use less resource.

---

**UPDATE:**

You can use a `setBackgroundResource` method to remain and change the background state of clicked button as follows:

```
// 1st clicklistener method
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_drawable);
        button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_drawable);
    }
}

// 2nd clicklistener method
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_drawable);
        button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_drawable);
    }
}
```

Not tested but it should work.

Comment: Alright thats great thanks! Now would their be a way to make the button stay green after it has been clicked? Then when another button is clicked that button turns green? Like radio buttons, but without using radio buttons.

Comment: @theGuy05 I updated my answer, I didn't test this but this should do the trick. Let me know if it's working. HTH